# Did Anakin steal C-3PO?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, attack-of-the-clones

In *Attack of the Clones*, when Anakin and Padme decide to rescue Obi-Wan, C-3PO is in the ship with them. Does the novelization or a deleted scene or something explain why he was there? Did Anakin steal him? Did the Lars give him to Anakin? Did Anakin claim legal ownership?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per the AOTC [Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(junior_novelization))

> "Padmé looked at Anakin uncertainly, but he only nodded and rose to
>   his feet. They made a hasty farewell to the Lars homestead, and **Owen
>   told Anakin to take C-3PO with him.** Then they all hurried back to
>   Padmé’s starship to play Obi-Wan’s message.".

A similar scene takes place in the [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/164035.Star_Wars_Episode_II), albeit slightly before Anakin arrives;

> “Well, Padmé,” Owen said, and when she turned to regard him, Padmé saw
>   that he was grinning widely. **“I’m returning this droid to Anakin. I
>   know that’s what my mom would want.”**
>
> Padmé smiled and nodded.

So the answers to your specific questions are yes, no, yes and apparently (albeit the Jedi don't typically own things).